# Cipher/Decipher Python Beginner Program

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

Question: Can someone edit my 2 lines of code?

Just wanted to point out that this is for a school assignment so I don't want to post all my code to prevent copy/plagiarism issues. Since I'm only having difficulties with a small requirement of the assignment, I don't think all my code is required anyways.

Requirement from the assgn I'm referring to:

> Newx=ord(x)+3
>   Newx will be an integer. To find out what letter that integer represents you can use the chr function as in:
>   actualLetter = chr(x)
>   Write a function named cipher that takes a string and a key (integer). The function ciphers the string into
>   another string and returns the new string. Note that when we reach 'z', and we want to add the key, we must
>   'roll' into the alphabet one more time, hence ord('z')+3 should give us ord('c').

When I run and test my program and input 'z', I don't get 'c', I get: [image: screenshot of running program]

My code for this portion of the program that results in this issue is:

```
example_string = letters[((ord(i)+key)%97)%26]
example2_string += letters[((ord(i)-key)%97)%26]
```

(example_string and example2_string are fake names)

Comment: I've seen you haven't been accepting answers for some time now, even if good answers are given. Please do try and provide feedback, upvote and accept answers; it's the best way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be performing anything modulo 97. Only perform modulo 97 if you have an alphabet of 97 characters.

The correct way of doing this is:

1. determine if the character is a letter;
2. convert the letter to a number between 0 and the size of the alphabet (the common ABC is of course 26 characters in size);
3. add or subtract the key value, modulo the size of the alphabet (for these kind of operations you can simply first add / subtract and then perform the modulus);
4. convert the resulting number to a letter again, this is your ciphertext.

So you would get:

```
alphabetSize = ord('z') - ord('a') + 1

k = 3
c = 'z'

if (ord(c) >= ord('a')) | (ord(c) <= ord('z')):
    n = ord(c) - ord('a')
    n = (n + k) % alphabetSize
    ctc = chr(n + ord('a'))
else:
    ctc = c

print ctc
```

the magic (in this case encryption because of the `+` being used before key `k`) is of course in the 3 lines within the `if` statement. Those can be combined of course - if need be into one single line - but this is more neat.

Answer (score 0):

I think the modulo 97 is at the wrong position. You should do ord(i)%97-3 then it works.

```
chr(ord('a')+(ord('z')%97-3)%26)
example_string = letters[((ord(i)%97+key)%26]
```

Another thing that you could do would be to subtract a from z and then do your subtraction like this:

```
chr(ord('a')+(ord('z')-ord('a')-3)%26)
```